# ideal Payment gateway issue with Amount

Tags: php, mysql

I am sending amount `2EUR` to the gateway and now it replace with `0,02`. Which causing wrong amount is being received at ideal and testing status is not getting update.

```
$amount = 2;    
$newAmount = 2.2;
```

What could have cause this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to multiple amount by 100

As mentioned in its documentation.

> All amounts (amount, itemPrice) should be given in whole eurocents.
>   Therefore, for a product costing 1 euro you should enter “100“ as the
>   price. Decimals are not accepted.

Comment: What I'm using is completely different which has Config.conf file which contains all configuration information like MERCHANTID="",ACQUIRERURL="",PRIVATECERT="", etc..

this is compelete new stuff. Let me know what Am I suppose to enter as partners_id. is it same as MERCHANT ID ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to send 2 EUR you need to do:

```
$amount = 200; //2 * 100,which will show 2,00
```

Amount of the payment given in cents. For example, 10 EUR is 'amount=1000'.
Ref: [iDEAL API](http://www.mollie.nl/support/documentatie/betaaldiensten/ideal/en/)

Your conf file should be: like:

```
PRIVATEKEY=priv.pem
#enter your password below
PRIVATEKEYPASS=ownPassword
PRIVATECERT=cert.cer
CERTIFICATE0=webserver.cer
#ACQUIRERURL=ssl://idealtest.secure-ing.com:443/ideal/iDeal
#for the production environment use URL below:
ACQUIRERURL=ssl://ideal.secure-ing.com:443/ideal/iDeal
ACQUIRERTIMEOUT=10
#enter your merchant id below
MERCHANTID=your merchant id here
SUBID=0
#enter payment confirmation url
MERCHANTRETURNURL=http://localhost/idealmain/index.php
EXPIRATIONPERIOD=PT10M
#enter the path to the logfile below
LOGFILE=Connector_log.txt
TraceLevel = DEBUG,ERROR
#PROXY=Vul hier een proxyserver in (gebruik dit ALLEEN als de webshop achter een proxyserver zit)
#PROXYACQURL=vul hier de url van de acquirer in (gebruik dit ALLEEN als de webshop achter een proxyserver zit)
```

Comment: What I'm using is completely different which has Config.conf file which contains all configuration information like MERCHANTID="",ACQUIRERURL="",PRIVATECERT="", etc..

this is compelete new stuff. Let me know what Am I suppose to enter as partners_id. is it same as MERCHANT ID ?

Comment: i dont think there's partner id, you need to set MERCHANTID in conf file

Comment: Yes config file is exactly same. PLease check folowing url
http://www.auctionsquare.eu/myaccount/buycredits
usrname : mahendra
passwd: password

let me know what you think about implementation.